# How can I add "Terminate All" to an Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ide, ide-customization

I very regularly use `Terminate/Disconnect All` but find it cumbersome to switch to the Debug pane, right click, and find and select it in the menu.

How can I add it to a toolbar, or assign a hotkey to this command?

It is not displayed in `Customize Perspective` -> `Command Groups Availability`.

Comment: Confirmed in Eclipse Luna - there doesn't seem to be an available menu item or hotkey assignment for this command anywhere in sight. I guess your only other option would be to write your own plugin...

Comment: The Console view for a running app has a Terminate button.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, but not a `Terminate All`, sadly